# How to count completed jobs in a thread pool without sharing a single variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory

I have a thread pool that accepts jobs (function pointers + data), giving them to a worker thread to complete.    Some of the jobs are given a pointer to a completion count `std::atomic<uint32>` which they increment when done, so the main thread creating those jobs can know how many of those jobs have finished.

The problem though, is that 12+ threads are contending on a single `uint32`.  I've put a lot of work into separating jobs and their data along cache lines, so this is the only source of contention left I want to eliminate, but I'm not sure how best to solve this particular issue.

What would be the simplest way to gather the number of completed jobs, without sharing a single `uint32` between multiple threads?

(It's okay if the main thread has to refresh it's cache when it checks this count, I only want to avoid dirtying the cache of worker threads.  Also, the worker threads don't need to know the count, they only increment it, while the main thread can only read it.)

*update:*

I'm currently trying out the idea of not sharing a single count at all, but having a count for each worker thread that the main thread can add together when checking.  The idea being that the main thread pays the main price (which is fine since it's waiting to "join" anyway).

Here's the code I have in it's ugly cooked in 10 minutes form

```
class Promise {
    friend ThreadPool;
public:

    ~Promise() {
        // this function destroys our object's memory underneath us; no members with destructors
        m_pool->_destroyPromise(this);
    }

    void join() {
        while (isDone() == false) {
            if(m_pool->doAJob() == false){
                // we've no jobs to steal, try to spin a little gentler
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    }

    void setEndCount(uint32 count) {
        m_endCount = count;
    }

    bool isDone() {
        return m_endCount == getCount();
    }

    uint32 getCount() {
        uint32 count = 0;
        for (uint32 n = 0; n < m_countCount; ++n) {
            count += _getCountRef(n)->load();
        }
        return count;
    }

    uint32 getRemaining() {
        return m_endCount - getCount();
    }

private:
    // ThreadPool creates these as a factory
    Promise(ThreadPool * pool, uint32 countsToKeep, uint32 endCount, uint32 countStride, void * allocatedData)
        : m_pool(pool)
        , m_endCount(endCount)
        , m_countCount(countsToKeep)
        , m_countStride(countStride)
        , m_perThreadCount(allocatedData)
    {};

    // all worker IDs start at 1, not 0, only ThreadPool should use this directly
    std::atomic<uint32> * _getCountRef(uint32 workerID = 0) {
        return (std::atomic<uint32>*)((char*)m_perThreadCount + m_countStride * workerID);
    }

    // data
    uint32 m_endCount;
    uint32 m_countCount; // the count of how many counts we're counting
    uint32 m_countStride;
    ThreadPool * m_pool;
    void * m_perThreadCount; // an atomic count for each worker thread + one volunteer count (for non-worker threads), seperated by cacheline
};
```

*update two:*

Testing this, it seems to work quite well.  It's a pretty large structure unfortunately, 64 bytes * worker thread count (for me this is pushing a KB), but the speed trade is about 5%+ for the jobs I usually use.  I guess this could work for now.

Comment: Is it actually an issue? Just how often are you checking this number?

Comment: You could have a flag to indicate completion of a particular job and then add the flags to determine how many have completed.

Comment: @Shawn - It's only an issue when the job size is relatively small.  If a job is handling 16x16 pixels in a job that applies a blur to an image, it can take 5% of the execution time

Comment: You could increment the flag every 10 completed tasks? Exchange granularity for speed.

Comment: @AnneQuinn: When you have many tasks that take the same amount of time, you should chunk them to reduce scheduling overhead.

Comment: How do your threads know what to work on?

Comment: @DavisHerring - Currently jobs are chunked in groups of 16, but I'm trying to hide that detail from the user interface.  (`doAJob()` is misleading, it can steal up to 16)

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - They each have their own queue of jobs that are handed out semi-round robin (it tries to keep using the same thread until it becomes busy).  If a thread isn't doing anything, it'll look at other threads for job bundles it can steal without getting in the way

Comment: So could the main thread not simply check how may elements are still to be processed in all the queues?

Comment: Well OK, scratch that, that will not count stuff currently being processed…

Comment: I guess then having a completion counter per thread is not a bad solution. I would, however, argue that if contention from 12 threads on a completion counter gets to have a significant effect on overall performance, then maybe your jobs are way too small!?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel - That's what I thought too seeing the profiling results.  Unfortunately, chunking the jobs into groups of 64 causes other issues (it's harder to steal job chunks, so threads can get stuck with groups of really expensive jobs it can't redistribute as a worst case), and the jobs themselves are as big as I can make them (culling checks and matrix transforms on rendering objects)  For now, this might just have to be the middle ground I think.  Also I thought about giving jobs a "difficulty score", but that's... I'm too lazy to score each job like that aha...

Comment: Job stealing is the way to go and yes it's hard and invasive. But without it the scheduling overhead will kill performance for tiny jobs.